# TriLib SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipEntry - Cannot access a closed Stream for GetInputStream()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sharpziplib

(This is using Unity 2020.1.4f1 with Trilib 2.0.9 Model Loader)

I'm trying to extract the bytes from a zipStream (to load the `bytes[]` into a `Texture2D.LoadImage()` in Unity). How do you do this?

Here's what I have tried and the error I am getting:

> I'm getting the error: "Cannot access a closed Stream." for `Stream zipStream = zipFile.GetInputStream(e)` where `e` is a `ZipEntry` from
> a `ZipFile` (produced by a closed-source sdk)

```
 Stream zipStream = zipFile.GetInputStream(e); // error occurs here
 
      tex.LoadImage(ReadFully(zipStream));
      tex.Apply();
 

    public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

and `e` is extracted within a loop - if that matters

```
foreach (ZipEntry e in zipFile)
        {
            if (e.IsFile)
            { ...
```

```
ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
System.IO.MemoryStream.Seek (System.Int64 offset, System.IO.SeekOrigin loc) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile.TestLocalHeader (ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipEntry entry, ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile+HeaderTest tests) (at <1a5a474a643a454ba874ca384c215100>:0)
ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile.LocateEntry (ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipEntry entry) (at <1a5a474a643a454ba874ca384c215100>:0)
ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile.GetInputStrea
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Unity stuff, but still I would want to see the full method that you are using so I can see how the stream is being fetched and passed.

Comment: All I have is the `ZipFile` as an object - I am able to iterate it to get its `ZipEntry`, and `e.Name` seems to work... maybe the question is how do you open the `ZipFile` for extracting individual `ZipEntry` streams?

Comment: So, do you want to open a zipped file and read the individual file from it, right?

Comment: No... the ZipFile is already passed in code as some sort of ZipFile object

Comment: I have a zipped file loaded in a `ZipFile` object. I am getting back its entries and the stream object from it. See this sample, https://prnt.sc/vcv2z0

Comment: I think the issue might be that the SDK is producing a `ZipFile` and closing it before I can access it. How do re-open it or how you create a new `ZipFile` from a closed `ZipFile`?

Comment: It depends, we are not able to see the complete code as we do not know about what is causing it to close the stream, or maybe it is you unknowingly closing the stream.

Comment: I have not called .Close() on it. SO I get the ZipFile by calling sdkinstance.ZipFile... I can loop thru to get the file names, but when I try getting the streams, the error above occurs

Comment: in your snippet, the error also occurs in the same using getInputStream line

Comment: While I am able to correctly load the stream, Can you share complete method of yours so I can reproduce the error as I can't do it because it works from my side. See: https://prnt.sc/vcvcjq

Comment: Instead of opening from file system, can you try creating a new ZipFile using an existing ZipFile object?

Comment: my issue is line 92 in your snippet. it could be due to "System.ObjectDisposedException 
The ZipFile has already been closed"

Comment: I am not sure about how are you going to create a `ZipFile` from the `ZipFile` object. It doesn't directly accept a zipfile object in the constructor to clone it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224065/discussion-between-jamshaid-kamran-and-ina).

Comment: Hi, the approach of not using TriLib's downloader feature seems to work. Manually extract zip, use local model loader etc. Thanks you for this idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, we discussed the issue in chat and the problem with `ZipFile` was, it contained no File Name and no `Stream` in it. Which technically means, we cannot get stream of the individual files in the `ZipFile` object.

**Scenario:** They were using `TriLib` and passing the URL of the zip file that was available on a server. What `TriLib` did was, it fetched the file and information, parsed it in an object and returned the object into a method upon completion.

**The Problem:** `ZipFile` object contained no information regarding the Individual Files and their `Stream` neither it had a name, so the `Name` property was coming null. Which means, we couldn't perform any operation on the `ZipFile` object.

**Solution:** We made a custom downloader and downloaded the file onto disk, then passed the downloaded file to the `ZipFile` constructor, by using this approach, we had all the information inside of a zip file.

Comment: Thanks for the debug! Being a self-taught programmer, it really helped to see how someone else would debug a situation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that the input streams of each zip entry are connected to the input stream of the whole file. Closing that stream causes the file stream to close. Remove the using around the entry stream, and I believe your code should work.

Comment: I tried it without using at first. Same error. Added using just in case

Comment: how do you re-open a `ZipFile`?

Comment: @ina How are you creating the ZipFile? Are you sending a stream that is already closed? Or disposing your ZipFile?